# Python Ftp Not a Direcoty error

Tags: file, python-2.7, ftp, download

I am trying to download files from a ftp server and importing  the data to django. So i created a list contain server address,login details,path,file name,and the path  where the file to be download and pass to a function which do downloading. it is working file in my sytem when move it to client server it showing error like

" error downloading C_VAR1_31012014_1.DAT - [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'common/VARRate/C_VAR1_31012014_1.DAT"

this is how the list look like

`self.fileDetails = {
        'NSE FO VAR RATE FILE': ('ftp.xxx.com', username, passwd, 'common/VARRate', 'C_VAR1_\d{4}201[45]_\d{1}.DAT', 'Data/samba/Ftp/Capex10/NSECM/VAR RATE'),
                    }`

```
  for fileType in self.fileDetails:
        self.ftpDownloadFiles(fileType)
```

This details will pass to the function following function

```
def ftpDownloadFiles(self, fileType):
    logging.info('Started ' + str(fileType))
    try:
        ftpclient = ftplib.FTP(self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_SRV_POS],
                                self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_USR_POS],
                                self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_PSWD_POS],
                                timeout=120)
        #ftpclient.set_debuglevel(2)
        ftpclient.set_pasv(True)
        logging.info('Logged in to ' + self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_SRV_POS] +\
                          time.asctime())
        logging.info('\tfor type: '+ fileType)
    except BaseException as e:
        print e
        return

    remotepath = self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_PATH_POS]

    #matched, unmatched, downloaded = 0
    try:
        ftpclient.cwd(remotepath)
        ftpclient.dir(filetimestamps.append)
    except BaseException as e:
        logging.info('\tchange dir error : ' + remotepath + ' ' +\
                         e.__str__())
    self.walkTree(ftpclient, remotepath, fileType)
    #logging.info('\n\tMatched %d, Unmatched %d, Downloaded %d' 
    # % (matched, unmatched, downloaded))
    ftpclient.close()
```

From here it will call next function here the download process will start

```
def walkTree(self, ftpclient, remotepath, fileType):
    # process files inside remotepath; cwd already done
    # remotepath to be created if it doesnt exist locally
    copied=matched=downloaded=imported = 0
    files = ftpclient.nlst()

    localpath = self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_DSTPATH_POS]
    rexpCompiled = re.compile(self.fileDetails[fileType][FDTL_PATRN_POS])

    for eachFile in files:
        try:
            ftpclient.cwd(remotepath+'/'+eachFile)
            self.walkTree(ftpclient, remotepath+'/'+eachFile+'/', fileType)
        except ftplib.error_perm: # not a folder, process the file
            # every file to be saved in same local folder as on ftp srv
            saveFolder = remotepath
            saveTo = remotepath + '/' + eachFile
            if not os.path.exists(saveFolder):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(saveFolder)
                    print "directory created"
                except BaseException as e:
                    logging.info('\tcreating %s : %s' % (saveFolder, e.__str__()))
            if (not os.path.exists(saveTo)):
                try:
                    ftpclient.retrbinary('RETR ' + eachFile, open(saveTo, 'wb').write)
                    #logging.info('\tdownloaded '  + saveTo)
                    downloaded += 1
                except BaseException as e:
                    logging.info('\terror downloading %s - %s' % (eachFile, e.__str__()))
                except ftplib.error_perm:
                    logging.info('\terror downloading %s - %s' % (eachFile, ftplib.error_perm))  
            elif (fileType == 'NSE CASH CLOSING FILE'):  # spl case if file exists
                try:
                    # rename file
                    yr = int(time.strftime('%Y')) - 1
                    os.rename(saveTo, saveTo + str(yr))
                    # download it
                    ftpclient.retrbinary('RETR ' + eachFile, open(saveTo, 'wb').write)
                    downloaded += 1
                except BaseException as e:
                    logging.info('\terror rename/ download %s - %s' % (eachFile, e.__str__()))
```

Can any one help me to resolve this problem

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: when run this code in my system the file is getting downloaded properly,but when moved this code to my clients system  it is showing an error "error downloading C_VAR1_31012014_1.DAT - [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'common/VARRate/C_VAR1_31012014_1.DAT" .You can see i am recornding the error using log

Comment: Erorr is Happening at the function def walkTree because from there the log is getting saved

Comment: Can you tell me what the differences are between the 2 situations: both OS and both django versions and both python versions. One of them should cause the error. I always use django debug toolbar to see the versions (also of important third party packages I use), so you can see this right away.

Comment: If the error is in the logging,  show us the logging settings (in settings.py )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use os.path.join() in stead of the hardcoded slashes as path dividers for the os to download to. / or \ depends of the local os.

e.g. in your code:

```
saveTo = remotepath + '/' + eachFile
```

would become:

```
saveTo = os.path.join(remotepath,eachFile)
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: I done what you have mentioned but still it is showing the same @michel.iamit

Comment: See the comment at the question.. and why did you accept this as an answer, if it did not solve the problem? I miss info: what is the diference: on what operating system it is working and on which one isn't? could it be rights? does the process have rights to the folder? (on local develop system you usally have all rights, and so on, and so on)